# SwipeRefreshLayout getting stuck around RecyclerView inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have 4 lists: a ViewPager with the PagerTitleStrip. (Each swipe sideways shows a different list)
The fragment inside holds a single SwipeRefreshLayout around a RecylerView showing the relevant list information.

Swiping down to refresh - refreshes the visible list (all 4 work fine). But the first 3 lists the refresh circle will never disappear but the last one always correctly refreshes and finishes hiding the refresh circle.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

fragment_main

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/fragment_joblist"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/list"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:scrollbars="vertical"
      />
```

page_list

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Some of the source - setRefreshing(false) turns on the SwipeRefreshLayout for all lists but only stops it on the last 4th list page.

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private WeakReference<OnClickListener> mClickListener = null;
    private WeakReference<OnRefreshListener> mRefreshListener = null;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private JobListAdapter mJobListAdapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeLayout = null;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    private int selected = -1;
    private JobType mJobType;

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber, JobType jobType,
            OnClickListener clickListener, OnRefreshListener refreshListener) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        fragment.mJobType = jobType;
        fragment.mClickListener = new WeakReference<OnClickListener>(clickListener);
        fragment.mRefreshListener = new WeakReference<OnRefreshListener>(refreshListener);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mSwipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_joblist);
        mSwipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        mSwipeLayout.invalidate();

        if (mRefreshListener != null && mRefreshListener.get() != null)
            this.setOnRefreshListener(mRefreshListener.get());

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mJobListAdapter = new JobListAdapter(getJobSubset(), mJobType, this.getActivity(),
                mClickListener.get(), (MainActivity) this.getActivity());
        mJobListAdapter.setActivity((MainActivity) this.getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mJobListAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void setOnRefreshListener(OnRefreshListener refreshListener) {
        mRefreshListener = new WeakReference<OnRefreshListener>(refreshListener);
        mSwipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(mRefreshListener.get());
    }

    public void setRefreshing(final boolean b) {
        if (mSwipeLayout != null) {
            mSwipeLayout.setRefreshing(b);
            Log.e("Place ListFrag", "refreshing null");
    /*          
            mSwipeLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSwipeLayout.setRefreshing(b);
                    mSwipeLayout.invalidate();          
                }
            });         
    */
        }
    }

    /**
     * Refresh the list with the latest content
     */
    public void refresh() {
        if (mJobListAdapter != null) {
            mJobListAdapter.setData(getJobSubset());
            mRecyclerView.destroyDrawingCache();
            mRecyclerView.invalidate();
            mJobListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean setRefreshing(true) correctly refreshes all lists and shows the refresh indicator for all lists. But setRefreshing(false) never stops the refresh indicator on lists 1,2,3 but always works on list 4.

Comment: You can simply edit your question instead of commenting it ;)

Answer (score 1):

try it first check whether it refreshing or not and then do `setRefreshing(false)`

```
if(mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
     mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```